# Core Data Attributes Picture type

Tags: image, core-data

In Xcode you can see in the Core Data you can add attributes. My question is what kind of Type is a Picture?

[image: The Types of data]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no picture type in the Core Data. But you can store an UIImage as Data

```
let data:Data = img.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
```

Also if you prefer, you can store your UIImage as String(Base64).

```
let imageData = image.pngData()
let str:String = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength64Characters)
```

Comment: This is out-of-date code. Swift 4.2 does not use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation`.

Comment: OK, I've fixed them.